# Как в intellij idea отключить проверку кода?

Tags: intellij-idea

Сильно мешает подсветка неправильного кода. Использую среду разработки как редактор. Как отключить проверку кода и в то же время оставить подсказки и подсветку?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Editor</kbd> → <kbd>Inspections</kbd>. Выбираете какие проверки проводить, а какие нет