# Как запустить run в IntelliJ, если есть ошибки в коде?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как запустить такой код? Допустим, есть два класса, один с error`ами, другой нормальный. Класс с ошибками вообще не участвует в работе программы, но из-за него не получается протестить класс без ошибок. Вроде в IntelliJ можно поменять параметры запуска кода?

P.S. Писал тесты, но идея все равно выбрасывает исключения и не дает запустить тест.

UPD: [Этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502685/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-intellij-idea-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) не решает проблему, там про подсветку в IntelliJ, а у меня про IntelliJ, которая не дает скомпилировать код если там есть ошибки.

UPD2: Вот `JUnit` тест:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Board board = new Board();
    //initialization of the playing field (Board), checkers, etc.
    InitializeBoard initBoard = new InitializeBoard(board);
    initBoard.initialize();

    //start game
    CheckersGame game = new CheckersGame(board);
    game.start();
}
```

А если в `edit configurations` к тесту стaвлю `Build, no errors check`, то выходит такое исключение:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Представьте код пожалуйста

Comment: Было бы неплохо посмотреть на тесты и исключения которые выбрасываются при них

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в intellij idea отключить проверку кода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/502685/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-intellij-idea-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)

Comment: @Алексей тесты - такой же запуск, как через main. Исключения - такие же как в main. Точнее не исключения, а ошибки.

Comment: Понятно. Я думал вы юзаете, что то типа JUnit - в таком случае есть возможность прогонять тесты отдельно от основного кода. Ну это на будущее. А пока воспользуйтесь Exclude https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiler-excludes.html

Comment: @Алексей Это был JUnit. Хоть я и решил свою проблему, но мне все равно интересно, почему тест не запускался. Я добавил код в вопрос. 
Если что: ошибки такие же, как и при запуске main.

Comment: @Алексей P.S.  Думаю, что это не влияет, но junit я юзал через maven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В настройках запуска в `Edit Configurations` есть поле `Before launch: Build, Activate tool window` со списком действий, которые совершает IntelliJ перед запуском. По умолчанию там присутствует одно единственное действие `Build`. Замените его на `Build, no error check` и вы сможете запускать классы без ошибок, несмотря на наличие других классов с ошибками компиляции.

1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а потом такой код в git попадает.. лучше, код закоментировать, исправить, удалить

Comment: Попадает лишь у тех, кто компилирует исключительно IDE. В Eclipse это вообще поведение по-умолчанию.

Comment: вот-вот, новички так и делают с многомодульными проектами - в среде все классы друг друга видят, только maven про эти выкрутасы ничего не знает

Comment: @keekkenen Новички неинтересны. Иногда возникает необходимость запустить какой-то класс в то время, когда другие сломаны. Идти и комментировать всё, что сломано ради запуска одного класса непрактично. Перед коммитом в Git или в любой другой VCS необходимо произвести полную сборку при помощи Maven, Gradle или чем ваш проект обычно собирается. IDE не предназначена для конечной сборки проекта, она предназначена для разработки.

Answer (score 1):

Закомментировать проблемные участки.